# NSFetchedResultsController fetchAllGroupedBy no known method

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've implemented this method:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    _fetchedResultsController = [Email fetchAllGroupedBy:nil withPredicate:nil sortedBy:@"email_id" ascending:NO delegate:self];

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

but the Xcode says:

No known class method for selector 'fetchAllGroupedBy:withPredicate:sortedBy:ascending:delegate:'

Email : NSManagedObject

I also use MagicalRecord

Comment: Show implementation of Email please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MR_fetchAllGroupedBy:withPredicate:sortedBy:ascending:delegate:`
We've deprecated the shorthand notation.

Comment: oh this is my mistake I supposed that this iOS SDK method )